# Is there a way to stop a simulation after a set amount of time?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

Say I want a testbench simulation to run for 5000ns. Is there a way to tell the testbench to do this?

I'm aware I can edit simulation runtime in Vivado, but I want a way to do this in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to stop a simulation after a fixed amount of time is to use `$finish` in an `initial` block in the source code:

```
initial #5000ns $finish;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.2 *Simulation control system tasks*, for further details.

[See also ChipVerify](https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-initial-block)